# React onTransitionEnd event gets called frequently

Tags: reactjs

I have React code like this:

```
handleTransitionEnd() {
    console.log('ended');
}

<div onTransitionEnd={(ev) => this.handleTransitionEnd(ev)}....
```

The peculiar thing is that my logs are filling up with `ended`. Even if I don't have any transition css logic tied to the element at all. It seems to be firing on every state change or re render. Is this normal? I would expect it to only fire when a css transition ends.

Is there some other way this callback should be achieved?

Thanks

UPDATE:

here is a sandbox showing some strangeness: https://codesandbox.io/s/vy5wwyq5v3

Clicking the first button causes the callback to be called 3 times, then if you click the second button it gets called another 2 times even tho a transition doesn't happen. My app is even more extreme than this with it getting called a lot more often.

Comment: You should probably address the reason why your component is re-rendering. Can we see more of the code?

Comment: Shouldn't it only trigger transitionEnd? Regardless of other things. Docs seem lacking.

Answer (score 5):

The css transition being used `transition: "all 3s"` is causing transitions on multiple properties, not just margin-left.

In the example provided, `outline-color` and `outline-width` were transitioned as well. They were then transitioned again when clicking anywhere else (not just on the second button).

You can see this by checking the event:

```
onTransitionEnd={e => {
  e.persist();                 // see: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling
  console.log(e.propertyName);
}}
```

The css transition could be more specific: `transition: "margin-left 3s"` to avoid this.
Alternatively, test `e.propertyName` for the desired case.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what dabs said in his answer, the `transitionend` event bubbles. This means if any children of your element have transitions on them, they will trigger the transitionend event on themselves, then bubble up to their parent, triggering on each of them, including the current element that you have the listener on.

A simple way to check that you're only running your logic for the element your listener is on is to compare `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` like so:

```
onTransitionEnd={e => {
if ( e.target === e.currentTarget ) {
  // your logic here
}}
```

`e.target` is the element that starts the event, which can be one of the children, for example, not just the element with the listener on it.
`e.currentTarget` however always points to the element that has the listener on it, regardless of if it initiated the event or not.
By comparing the two, you can check that you're only running logic when it's the element with the listener on it that initiated it.