# Why do all DOM elements get removed when removing only one?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-transitions

There is one issue with custom To Do List project.

```js
// Varibles
//////////////////////////////////////////////
const plusButton = document.querySelector('.plus-button');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const addNewTaskButton = document.querySelector('.add-new-task-button');
const tasksList = document.querySelector('.tasks-list');
const newTaskInput = document.querySelector('.new-task-input');

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1. Show popup
const showPopup = () => {
  popup.classList.add('show');
  newTaskInput.focus();
};
// 2. Add new task
const addNewTask = () => {
  tasksList.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin',
    `<li class="task" ontransitionend="removeTask(event)">
        <span class="complete-task"></span>
        <input class="task-name" ondblclick="editTask(event)" onclick="saveTask(event)" value="${newTaskInput.value}" type="text" readonly />
        <span class="delete-task" onclick="deleteTaskAnimation(event)"></span>
      </li>`
  );

  newTaskInput.value = '';
  popup.classList.remove('show');
};

// 3. Delete task animation
const deleteTaskAnimation = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add('deleted');
};

// 4. Remove task
const removeTask = (event) => {

  event.currentTarget.remove();
};



//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Event listeners
//////////////////////////////////////////////
plusButton.addEventListener('click', showPopup);
addNewTaskButton.addEventListener('click', addNewTask);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, white 70%, #f3f3f3 100%);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #292d34;
}

body .aurora {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

body .aurora .one {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 1400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  background: linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(255, 180, 41, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 180, 41, 0.75) 100%);
  filter: blur(160px);
}

body .aurora .two {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 94, 39, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 94, 39, 0.75) 100%);
  filter: blur(240px);
}

body .aurora .three {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(229, 89, 68, 0) 0%, rgba(229, 89, 68, 0.75) 100%);
  filter: blur(160px);
}

.tasks-list-container {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}

.tasks-list {
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));
  backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
  border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(255, 180, 41, 0.2);
  padding: 24px;
}

.tasks-list .task {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(255, 180, 41, 0.2);
}

.tasks-list .task:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.tasks-list .task.deleted {
  transform: translateY(300px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.tasks-list .task .complete-task {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2ec083;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tasks-list .task .delete-task {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c02e35;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tasks-list .task .task-name {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #292d34;
  color: #240905;
  color: #240905;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.tasks-list .task .task-name.isEditing {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(255, 180, 41, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
}

.add-new-task-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.add-new-task-container .plus-button {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(255, 180, 41, 0.2);
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.add-new-task-container .plus-button img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 630px;
  min-width: 320px;
  z-index: 2000;
  visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  perspective: 1300px;
}

.popup .content {
  padding: 24px;
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(124, 130, 141, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  transform: rotateX(-70deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4.5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4.5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.popup .content .input-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.popup .content .input-container .new-task-input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #292d34;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(124, 130, 141, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(100px);
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.popup .content .title-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transform: translateY(80px);
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.popup .content .btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(120px);
  transition: all 0.9s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.popup .content .btn-container .btn {
  background: #ffb429;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(245, 159, 0, 0.25);
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup .content .btn-container .btn:hover {
  background: #ffa805;
}

.popup.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup.show~.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup.show .content {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.show .content .title-text {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.show .content .new-task-input {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.show .content .btn-container {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.show~.tasks-list-container {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="title-text">Add New Task</h1>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input class="new-task-input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <a class="btn add-new-task-button">ADD</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="tasks-list-container">
  <ul class="tasks-list"></ul>
  <div class="add-new-task-container">
    <button class="plus-button">
          +
        </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aurora">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mental-dev/pen/ZEvLVmp

When the **delete** button is clicked `deleteTaskAnimation` runs and when this transition ends the task is being removed from **HTML**.
It works as expected, except on the first element. When I delete the first task element then all others are being removed too.

Here is a short video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__CiSgvq8Yv2IfE_4iFuq9Y06l_SyzMz/view

Do you know why is it behaving in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Same core issue as here: [React onTransitionEnd event gets called frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52303820/4294399). The `ontransitionend` is firing more often than you intended.

For your question, this is specifically happening when the bottom task is removed.

Your SCSS says

```
.task {
    // ...
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

    // ...
    &:not(:last-of-type) {
      margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    &.deleted {
      transform: translateY(300px);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Then in your JS:

```js
const removeTask = (event) => {
  event.currentTarget.remove();
};
```

If we log `event.propertyName`, and we add two tasks to your list, we can see three logged css proprties when the last item is deleted. Note the last `margin-bottom`.

```
opacity
transform
margin-bottom
```

When the bottom `task` is removed:

- the next-to-bottom item is no longer `:last-of-type`
- selector `&:not(:last-of-type)` no longer applies
- `transition: all...` applies to the property `margin-bottom`
- the `ontransitionend` event listener is triggered on `margin-bottom`.
- the task is removed by `removeTask`
- repeat until empty

You likely want to keep all the transitions and not have list them out one by one, so to fix this, I recommend a check in your `removeTask` function:

```
const removeTask = (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.classList.contains('deleted'))
    event.currentTarget.remove();
};
```

That way, when the `transitionend` event is fired, you *only* remove the item if the `deleted` class has been applied to your task element.